# Colored graph isomorphism reduction to uncolored graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am trying to find a polynomial time reduction from the colored graph isomorphism to the regular graph isomorphism.
Doing a search on this problem, I found [this article](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dieter/Papers/3gi.pdf) and it seems like theorem 1 is the solution I am looking for, however I don't fully understand it.
Could someone please explain how the reduction works?

Comment: See this also [Number of Labels used in reduction of Isomorphism of Labelled Graph to Graph Isomorphism]http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1647695/179940

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"a polynomial time reduction from the colored graph isomorphism to the regular graph isomorphism"  ....

the below proof is due to ***Pascal Schweitzer***,

> Theorem 1 (reduction of colored to uncolored graph isomorphism). The
>   graph isomorphism problem for colored graphs polynomial-time reduces
>   to the uncolored graph isomorphism problem.
>
> Proof: Assume we are given
>   two colored graphs $G_1, G_2$ on $n$ vertices. If the sets of colors
>   used for the graphs are not equal, we reduce the problem to a
>   No-instance of uncolored graph isomorphism, i.e., some fixed pair of
>   non-isomorphic graphs.
>
> If the graphs use the same color set, we **attach**
>   **to every vertex** a **rooted tree**,
>   whose isomorphism type is in **one-to-one**
>   **correspondence with the color of the vertex**: We choose a canonical
>   bijection of the color set to the set of rooted trees for which every
>   leaf is at height $⌈log2(n)⌉$ and which has a maximum degree of $3$. Such
>   a bijection is given by the following method: We number the colors
>   with integers in $\{0, . . . , n − 1\}$. To a color with binary encoding
>   $ a_0 a_1 . . . a_{⌈log2 n−1⌉}$ we assign the tree for which every vertex on
>   height $i$ has exactly  $a_i + 1$ children. We obtain two new graphs $G′_ 1$,
>   $G′ _2$ of size at most $O(n^2)$. By induction on the height, it is easy to
>   show that these new graphs are isomorphic if and only if the original
>   graphs are.