# Number of Labels used in reduction of Isomorphism of Labelled Graph to Graph Isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, graph-isomorphism

From "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" by Christoph M. Hoffmann ,

> Assume that both $X$ and $X'$ have $n$ vertices. We plan to code the
>   graph labels as suitable subgraphs which we attach to the vertices of
>   $X$ and of $X'$. In time polynomial in the length of the input we can rename 
>   the labels and may assume, therefore, that $L = \{1 ..... k\}$ is
>   the set of labels assigned by $\lambda$ and $\mu$. **Note that $k\leq2n$** .We describe
>   how to construct $Z$ from $(X,\lambda)$. The construction of
>   $Z'$ is done in the same way. Let $X = (V,E), V = \{v_1..... v_n\}$.
>   Intuitively, we obtain $Z$ from $X$ by attaching to each vertex $v_i$ a
>   complete graph with $n + r$ vertices, where $\lambda (v_i) = r$. **Note that $r\leq2n$.**
>   The vertices of the attached complete graph will be, for $v_i$, $\{v_{(i,1)},..... v_{(i,n+r)} \}$
>    The subgraph is atached to $v_i$ by an edge $(v_i, v_{i,1})$.
>
> It is easy to see that $(X,\lambda)$ is
>   isomorphic to $(X,\mu)$ iff $Z$ is isomorphic to $Z'$. **Since there are at most**
>   **$2n$ distinct labels**, the graphs $Z$ and $Z'$ have no more than
>   $2n^2+n$ vortices each and can thus be constructed in
>   polynomial time.

the definition of graph label is given as-

> Let $X = (V,E)$ be a graph, $\lambda$ is  a mapping from $V$ onto a set $L = \{ l_1,...l_k\}$.
>    Then the pair  $(X,\lambda)$ is a labelled graph.

Question 1: Why $k\leq 2n$ which implies $r\leq2n$?   It seems that it should be $k\leq n$ since [the passage of wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_labeling) tells

> When used without qualification, the term labeled graph generally
>   refers to a vertex-labeled graph with all labels distinct. Such a
>   graph may equivalently be labeled by the consecutive integers $\{1, …,
> > |E |\}$, where $|E |$ is the number of vertices in the graph.

**Question 2:**  What is the explanation of -

> Since there are at most
>   $2n$ distinct labels, the graphs $Z$ and $Z'$ have no more than
>   $2n^2+n$ vortices each and can thus be constructed in

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer of Jim is good. $k\leq 2 n$ because you have to consider both $\mu$ and $\lambda$. If they have different labels the total number of unique label can be $2n$. (Of course one can argue that if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ does not share the same set of labels that $(X,\lambda)$ and $(X',\mu)$ have no chance to be isomorphic, thus you could first look whether $\mu$ and $\lambda$ share the same labels and then consider $k\leq n$. But that is not the point of the proof here.)

For your second question it is an upper bound of the worst case scenario which gives the bound $2n^2+n$.

The intuition of the proof is to encode the labels of $(X,\lambda)$ and $(X',\mu)$ by connecting the vertices to new fresh vertices.
To do this they assume that the labels are between $1$ and $2n$ (which is the first part that confused you). Then they encode that a vertex $v$ has label $j$ by connecting $v$ in $Z$ to $j$ new vertices (note that only $v$ will be connected to this vertices).

So you have to introduce $\lambda(v)$ new vertices for each $v\in X$ in order to build $X$. Thus in $X$ you have exactly $n+\sum_{v\in X}\lambda(v)$ vertices. but you know that $\lambda(v)\leq 2n$ thus you get:
\begin{align}
|Z| &=n+\sum_{v\in X}\lambda(v) \\
& \leq n+\sum_{v\in X}2n = n+n2n = 2n^2+n  
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

**My interpretation:**

The Confusion arises, here-

> Assume that both $X$ and $X'$ have $n$ vertices. We plan to code the
> graph labels as suitable subgraphs which we attach to the vertices of
> $X$ and of $X'$. In time polynomial in the length of the input we can rename
> the labels and may assume, therefore, that $L = \{1 ..... k\}$ is
> the set of labels assigned by $\lambda$ and $\mu$. **Note that $k\leq2n$** .

One needs to note that-

> we can rename the labels and may assume, therefore, that $L = \{1 ..... k\}$ is the set of labels
>
> **assigned by $\lambda$ and $\mu$.**

So, if you have $k\leq n$, then there is a *guarantee* or *certainty*,that there exists an Isomorphism  from $X$ to $X'$ already, since, if $k\leq n$ then it is certain that $\exists i,j$ such that $ \lambda(v_i)=r=\mu(v_j)$ where $ 1\leq i,j \leq n$.

But if $k\leq 2n$, then $\lambda(v_i)$ may take $n$ different label, and  $\mu(v_j)$ may take $n$ different label.

For example, consider Cyclic Graph $C_4$ and Complete Graph $K_4$. Add 1 vertex  to 1st,2 vertices  to 2nd,3 vertices  to 3rd, 4 vertices  to 4th vertex   of $C_4$ and $K_4$ and rename them as $C'_4$ and $K'_4$. Now you have to use 14 different labels in $C'_4$, and none of them can be used in  $K'_4$. Note that the number of vertices is same in both $C'_4$ and $K'_4$. Here, $|L|=2n=28$;

So, $k\leq2n$.