# Coloring/Labelling problem in Polynomial reduction of Isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, coloring, graph-isomorphism

** Question :**   Notice the  inequality inside yellow box. If $i_1$ has $n$ possible vertex, then $j$ has maximum $(n-1)$ vertices. For $\mu_{i_1,j}$ , it should be $1\leq j \leq (n-1)$ .

but it is written that, $1\leq j \leq n$ . Why?

**Relevent Question :**  what does $\mu_j(i)={ \begin{cases} 
      1 &  If \ \ \  i=1 \\
      0 & Otherwise
   \end{cases}
}$ mean?

[image]
[image]

- From "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" by Christoph M. Hoffmann

Comment: The inequality is indeed $1\leq j\leq n$. But you are right $j$ has only $n-1$ possible vertices, but there are no guaranties that the picked vertex for  i is the $n^{th}$ so the equation is  $1\leq j\leq n$ $\mathbf{j\neq i_1}$.

Comment: @wece if  $1 \leq j \leq n$ then you are labeling same vertex twice , i.e. there will be a graph which will have  a vertex that is  labeled with  $i_1$ and $i$.

Comment: No because there is the $j\neq i_1$

Comment: if you take $j\leq n-1$ you assume that $i_1=n$ which may not be the case in general

Comment: @wece Got it thanks for patience, it was rather a silly query! one has to check all possible vertex as 2, so $j$ needs to be all $n$ vertices.

Comment: @wece is $1 \leq i_1 \leq (n-1)$ ?

Comment: I posted an answer in the hope to clear things up to you. Please tell me if that not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the idea of the proof is to build an isomorphism from $X$ to $X'$. To do that they use labelling on the vertices.

The first paragraph state that you can know whether $X$ and $X'$ are isomorphic by checking whether $(X,0)$ and $(X',0)$ are (where $0$ is the labelling function that assign $0$ as the label of all vertices). Thus now we assume that $X$ and $X'$ are isomorphic.

Now thee idea is to find incrementally for each vertex of $X$ a matching vertex in $X'$.

For simplicity I denote $X=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and $X'=\{u_1, ...,u_n\}$

First they give a labelling $\lambda_1$ that label $v_1$ with $1$ and all other $v_j$ (with $j>1$) with $0$. And $\mu_j$ label $u_j$ with $1$ and all the other $u_i$ (with $i\neq j$) with 0.

Since $X$ and $X'$ are isomorphic we know that there exist an isomorphism between $X$ and $X'$ and that isomorphism must match $v_1$ with some $u_{i_1}\in X'$. Hence, for $(X,\lambda_1)$ and $(X,\mu_{i_1})$ are isomorphic.

So we have found the first matching for $v_1$ witch is $u_{i_1}$. We will now look for a vertex matching $v_2$ assuming that $v_1$ is matched by $u_{i_1}$.

To do this we use other labelling function. Since $v_1$ is matched by $u_{i_1}$ we label them by the same thing $1$. Since we look for a matching for $v_2$ we label it by a new label: 2. to find the good match we try all the possible labelling for $X'$ that assign $1$ to $u_{i_1}$ and $0$ to all other vertex except for one which is labeled by $2$. This vertex is the candidate for being the matching of $v_2$. They denote such labelling by $\mu_{i_1,j}$, where $i_1$ is the matching for $v_1$ and $j$ is the candidate matching for $v_2$.

With the same argument as before we know that there exists an isomorphism, thus there exists a matching for $v_2$ thus there exists $i_2$ such that  $(X,\lambda_2)$ is isomorphic to $(X',\mu_{i_1,i_2})$.

And you continue like that until you found $i_1,i_2,...,i_n$ with is an isomorphism for $X$ to $X'$.

So to address your question, the only think we know on $i_1$ is that $1\leq i_1\leq n$.

The only think we know on $i_2$ is that $i_1\neq i_2$ and $1\leq i_2 \leq n$. (That why the contain on $j$ when defining the $\mu_{i_1,j}$ is $i_1\neq j$ and $1\leq j \leq n$). Indeed $1\leq j \leq n$ does not give a bound on the number of possible candidates for the label $2$ it only says that this candidate is a vertex of $X'$. The only thing that gives you a 'bound' is to know that it cannot be $i_1$.

I hope it helps you

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Now , does $1\leq j \leq n$ tell  that $j$ could be any vertex from $1$  to  $n$ except $i_1$? it has $(n-1)$ possibilities and it could  be anyone from   $1$  to  $n$ ?

Comment: 1)  in that case, the inequality $1\leq j \leq n$ is not a "Bound" , i.e. $1\leq j \leq n$ does not  tell the number of possible 

candidates for label 2. right? In that case , please incorporate/add this and the previous comment to your answer.Also,  there is a 

typo  $u_{i - 1}$ should be $u_{i_1}$. 2) would you please take a look at the post http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1647695/257587  and answer?

Comment: I was expecting a response  from you, if you have time as you wrote ' Please tell me if that not the case.

Comment: @MikeSQ Thank you for the typo. I tried to include your comment in the answer. I'll take a look at the other question. Sorry for the delay, I got quite busy this days.